# Memory retain and release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I wanted to know that if I am doing correctly, regarding retain and release of digitbutton reference down below. In the book "Programming in Objective C by Stephen Kochan", it says in one section with different example that like digitbutton is holding reference to same object that sender is holding, so in between sender may get released elsewhere and then I would be calling currenttitle method on deallocated digitbutton, if that is the case.

So here I called retain on digitbutton and after its use I called release on it. Well, the example maybe not genuine for this purpose but is this concept valid? Should I make practice to retain objects like in example below?

I am not experienced in writing managed codes.

```
- (IBAction)clickDigit:(id)sender {
    UIButton *digitButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    [digitButton retain];
    NSLog(@"%@",[digitButton currentTitle]);
    [[self displayOutput] setText:[digitButton currentTitle]];
    [digitButton release];
}
```

### Update

Yes, the example was wrong; let's say if instead of id sender there is NSString and instead of UIButton, same NSString, and return type is just void. Then do I have to retain sender NSString for safety in case someone holding its reference releases it.

Note: I am not using ARC.

Comment: How would sender get released while your method runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in `clickDigit:` is unnecessary.

Instead of me explaining why it is unnecessary, I will point you directly to where I learned proper memory management techniques: [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Re: "unnecessary": Note that ARC apparently does the same thing, though (retaining method arguments): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310441/why-does-arc-retain-method-arguments

Comment: In fact, it would be best for you to explain why it is unecessary. SO answers should be mostly self-contained, using links only as backup.

Comment: @thilo not if you are using an optimized build. Also, arc doesn't call release/retain on the object but calls much more leightweight handlers in the ObjC runtime (so no IMP lookup or other dynamic stuff needed)

Comment: So i shouldn't be bothered by calling release and retain like in above example?? Thanks

Comment: @bloodwing Not if you know that there might be a race condition which results in the object getting deallocated while you are using it. If you don't use multithreading, you are perfectly fine, if you use multithreading, you are probably saved by your locking mechanism (but check your code)

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to retain & release it.

You can do like this

```
 - (IBAction)clickDigit:(UIButton *)sender 
 {

    NSLog(@"%@",[sender currentTitle]);
   [[self displayOutput] setText:[sender currentTitle]];

 }
```