# Does passing an object as a parameter for a method increment its retain counter under ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ARC retain method arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310441/why-does-arc-retain-method-arguments)

Under ARC, when I pass an object as a parameter for a method, does it make the retain counter of the object increment behind the scenes?

As I see it, knowing the answer might have some important implications for multithreading programming when one thread creates an object strongly referenced by a pointer and passes the reference to another thread for some long-term use while, in the original thread, the pointer is destroyed soon after the message was sent and thus the retain counter decrements simply because the `{}` scope in which the pointer was declared has ended, as a result the object is deallocated, therefore the second thread unexpectedly loses the object while in the middle of something, which makes the program crash. But if the retain counter of an object does grow by one when it's passed to a method, this problematic situation would not arise.