# Can an Objective-C object remove itself in its method (ARC is enabled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

In some reason, I have to use a design pattern that an object remove itself from its container, consider the following code(ARC is enabled, LCDObject is an object class, LCDContainer is a container class), in the whole program, object 's reference count is always 1 until it is removed from the container(reference count become 0), as comment 2 mention, when `[_container removeObject:self]` return, the object's reference count is 0, it is dealloc, right?, but the process is still in the object's method -- "removeFromContainer", what would happen? Does the following code would be execute successfully? Does "`removeFromContainer`" can return successfully?

I run this code in Xcode, the "NSLog" in "removeFromContainer" can be invoked successfully, but I can't figure out why...

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LCDContainer : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;
- (void)removeObject:(id)object;
- (id)addObject:(id)object;

@end

@implementation LCDContainer

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)addObject:(id)object {
    [_objects addObject:object];
    return object;
}

- (void)removeObject:(id)object {
    [_objects removeObject:object];
}

@end

//-------------------------------------------------------------
@interface LCDObject : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) LCDContainer *container;
- (id)initWithContainer:(LCDContainer*) container;
- (void)removeFromContainer;

@end

@implementation LCDObject

- (id)initWithContainer:(LCDContainer *)container {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _container = container;
        // (1) add the object to the Container, now its reference count is 1
        //
        [container addObject:self];
        NSLog(@"add to container.");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)removeFromContainer {
    // (2) remove the object from the Container, now its reference count is 0,
    //     the object is delete, does the following "NSLog" would be invoked successfully? 
    //
    [_container removeObject:self];
    NSLog(@"remove from container.");
}

@end

//-------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        LCDContainer *container = [[LCDContainer alloc] init];
        [[LCDObject alloc] initWithContainer:container];
        [[[container objects] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromContainer];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Override `dealloc` and throw a `NSLog` in there (calling super, of course) to see when that's called.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried your code but I suspect it will work. sapi's suggestion (adding a breakpoint or NSLog on dealloc) is a good one to confirm, though.

Thee are two ways that ARC could be doing this. You can check the assembler if you're really interested.

The simplest is to assume that it's using `autorelease`, that is, when an object is removed from your container it gets added to the autorelease pool and is released (and dealloced) at the end of the current run loop.

The other way is to consider *where* ARC adds its retains and releases. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310441/why-does-arc-retain-method-arguments) notes that your remove method *really* looks like this:

```
- (void)removeObject:(id)object {
    [object retain];
    [_objects removeObject:object];
    [object release];
}
```

The call *to* `removeObject:` may well have the same logic. This means that object does not get released as soon as the `removeObject:` call is completed; the object lifecycle is almost certainly (slightly) longer than that.