# Why does @objc generate retain and release calls?

Tags: objective-c, swift, assembly

I'm looking into how the `@objc` annotation in Swift affects the generated assembly code. From what I can tell, this annotation generates a trampoline function which performs two functions:

1. Moves the `self` argument from `x0` into `x20` to conform to the Swift ABI
2. Calls `retain` and `release` on all of the arguments (before and after the call into Swift code, respectively)

Here is the assembly code of the `scene:WillConnectTo:options:` trampoline from an iOS app, for example:

```
MyApp`@objc SceneDelegate.scene(_:willConnectTo:options:):
    0x102a850fc <+0>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #-0x40]!
    0x102a85100 <+4>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
    0x102a85104 <+8>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
    0x102a85108 <+12>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x102a8510c <+16>:  add    x29, sp, #0x30            ; =0x30 
    0x102a85110 <+20>:  mov    x19, x4
    0x102a85114 <+24>:  mov    x20, x3
    0x102a85118 <+28>:  mov    x21, x2
    0x102a8511c <+32>:  mov    x22, x0
    0x102a85120 <+36>:  bl     0x102a85640               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x102a85124 <+40>:  mov    x23, x0
    0x102a85128 <+44>:  mov    x0, x21
    0x102a8512c <+48>:  bl     0x102a85640               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x102a85130 <+52>:  mov    x21, x0
    0x102a85134 <+56>:  mov    x0, x20
    0x102a85138 <+60>:  bl     0x102a85640               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x102a8513c <+64>:  mov    x24, x0
    0x102a85140 <+68>:  mov    x0, x19
    0x102a85144 <+72>:  bl     0x102a85640               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x102a85148 <+76>:  mov    x19, x0
    0x102a8514c <+80>:  mov    x0, x21
    0x102a85150 <+84>:  mov    x20, x22
    0x102a85154 <+88>:  bl     0x102a853a4               ; function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Dead, Arg[2] = Dead> of MyApp(_: __C.UIScene, willConnectTo: __C.UISceneSession, options: __C.UISceneConnectionOptions) -> () at SceneDelegate.swift:17
->  0x102a85158 <+92>:  mov    x0, x21
    0x102a8515c <+96>:  bl     0x102a85634               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x102a85160 <+100>: mov    x0, x24
    0x102a85164 <+104>: bl     0x102a85634               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x102a85168 <+108>: mov    x0, x19
    0x102a8516c <+112>: bl     0x102a85634               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x102a85170 <+116>: mov    x0, x23
    0x102a85174 <+120>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x102a85178 <+124>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
    0x102a8517c <+128>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
    0x102a85180 <+132>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp], #0x40
    0x102a85184 <+136>: b      0x102a85634               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
```

I understand why we need (1), but what is the purpose of (2)? In what scenario would these extra `retain` and `release` calls be necessary? Why can't we simply forward all of the arguments directly to the Swift function? I'm guessing there is a way for the Objective-C objects to be deallocated in the middle of the Swift function, but I'm having trouble thinking of an example of how this can happen.

Comment: I think it's because ObjC and Swift's calling conventions differ w.r.t. whose responsibility it is to retain arguments to function calls https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-to-change-the-default-ownership-for-passing-parameters/10261

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the link, that was an insightful read! That said, I am still not clear on why we need the extra retain/release if the Swift function would maintain the refcount invariant anyways. I suppose one extra retain would be needed at the start if Swift did take ownership of the object (AFAIK Obj-C has the same "+0" ownership model), but then why not remove the extra `retain` altogether instead of adding a `release` when the ABI was changed?

Comment: @AndrewSun I think it's the DaveZ's reason from the link above "In practice, the outermost stack retain/release exists to ensure that the object is kept alive just in case one of the callees causes the stack reference to become the last reference." I would ask on the forum thread for an example that can reproduce that.

Comment: Hmm, after more research it seems like this is not unique to Swift/ObjC interop; the compiler does this for normal ObjC functions as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310441/why-does-arc-retain-method-arguments